# getting R Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument when applying bestglm( ) function

Tags: r

I am trying to make a model selection in ordinal logistic regression in R using bestglm() function to find the best subset. However, I got the error like this:
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Here is the code I have, and for the dataframe alt_m1, all variables are factors except one continuous explanatory variable.

```
bestglm(alt_m1, family = binomial, IC = "AIC", method = "exhaustive")
```

I have no ideas how to fix it. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: # Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for others to help?

Comment: Could you show as the structure of `alt_m1`. And I am not sure if `family = binominal` is correct here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "y" should be the last column in the dataset, works for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was due to the input Xy was a tibble instead of a dataframe, as.data.frame() before calling bestglm() works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).